# phpspreadsheet sample not working

Tags: php, composer-php, phpspreadsheet

I installed phpspreadsheet into my project using composer and I was trying to run the samples server by command line. The server was working, also shows the index page and sample links but when I click the sample links it says

**"The requested resource /C:/xampp/htdocs/bookshelftp/public/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/samples/index.php was not found on this server."**

I included autoload.php file in my index file also

Comment: how did you try to run samples? like `php  vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/samples/Autofilter/10_Autofilter.php`?

Comment: i used this code to run the sample server from phpspreadsheet doc "php -S localhost:8000 -t vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/samples" and i was trying to run the sample from that server

Comment: How did you try to access the examples on the server (i.e. which URL did you try to browse)?

Comment: i used localhost:8000, it gives the list of example link on the browser

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. I fixed it by editing Header.php (directly under the 'samples' directory) line 9 with this: `require_once __DIR__ . '/../src/Bootstrap.php';`
That 'Bootstrap.php' file, which is supposed to be there when you install with composer and "--prefer-source" did NOT get installed, so I had to copy it from a downloaded version and put it under the 'src' directory. One would think this would not have been as error-prone as it is, but it is a free product and pretty robust when you get it working.